# Buster to Bullseye upgrade followed by a downgrade back to Buster

Tags: debian, upgrade

I want to switch from Debian Buster to Debian Bullseye. After doing this, can I return all Bullseye packages to Buster? (Unupgrade packages)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Technically, you can, but downgrades aren’t supported and we don’t test them. The downgrade might work fine, but it might not, and Bullseye is now sufficiently far ahead of Buster that I wouldn’t try it.

Answer (score 9):

Stephen Kitt is correct.  It's not supported. But if you have nothing to lose, this is how you'd do it:

1. Set your sources to buster:

   ```
   sudo sed -i                \
     -e 's/bullseye/buster/g' \
     -e 's/unstable/buster/g' \
     -e 's/stable/buster/g'   \
     -e 's/testing/buster/g'  \
     -e 's/sid/buster/g'      \
     /etc/apt/sources.list    \
     /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
   ```
2. Tell apt to set `buster` as your preferred release and set a priority that allows downgrades by creating `/etc/apt/preferences.d/buster` with this:

   ```
   Package: *
   Pin: release n=buster
   Pin-Priority: 1001
   ```
3. Say a little prayer
4. Perform the "upgrade":

   ```
   # Upgrade
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt upgrade
   sudo apt dist-upgrade
   sudo apt --fix-broken install
   sudo apt autoremove
   ```
5. Cycle through `upgrade`, `dist-upgrade`, `--fix-broken install` and `autoremove` over and over until apt finishes successfully everywhere.
6. Celebrate because **if** you get here, then things probably worked out ok.
7. Remove `/etc/apt/preferences.d/buster` so it doesn't affect you in the future.

Comment: I followed your procedure and it worked pretty well - I had to `apt remove` some stuff manually because they were conflicting when doing `apt upgrade`, and `dist-upgrade` failed the first time but in the end everything looks fine. Just a warning: do not try this through SSH because the `dist-ugprade` just kicked me during the process and I had to restore a snapshot.